# How to add pagination in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have tried as following code in my template file  in wordpress...

```
 <?php query_posts('showposts=3&post_type=packages&order=ASC&paged='.$paged) ?>
```

It's not working... Please help me!!! I am a beginner in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

first parameter is your seperator between links

second parameter is previous page

third parameter is next page

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
<?php posts_nav_link(' &#183; ', 'previous page', 'next page'); ?>
</div>
```

you can replace them with images as well

```
<?php posts_nav_link( ' ', '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/images/prev.jpg" />', '<img src="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/images/next.jpg" />' ); ?>
```